# Wan't to declare a Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle

I just learned about trigger and I'm trying to create a trigger which give us an alert when we try to insert a row in a location table. The condition as to be for the client to have already return is previous book, so if it's previous location is > 30 days without being return the trigger shows up.

But I'm struggling with the form. If I correctly get what my lessons said this trigger can't be done with and "old.", so I tried something like that :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BookStillR
    BEFORE INSERT ON LOCATION
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if inserting then
        if (DATELOCATION >= SYSDATE-30 )  then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('A book exceeding the 30 days location has to be return.');
        end if;
    end if;
END;
/
```

But apparently SQL don't know dateLocation, I don't really get why. We're not suppose to create a select or at least I don't think, and the table exist... So I'm lost.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `:NEW` bind variable to access the column values and `DBMS_OUTPUT` will not be seen from a trigger, you want to raise an exception:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BookStillR
  BEFORE INSERT ON LOCATION
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING AND :new.DATELOCATION >= SYSDATE-30 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(
      -20000,
      'A book exceeding the 30 days location has to be return.'
    );
  END IF;
END;
/
```

I'm also assuming that `>=` should be `<=` to match the error message.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=76170484c65676691b8ec38147cb3790)*

Comment: That was fast ! Thanks a lot for your answer it works perfectly and thanks for your explanation about :NEW as well. PS: Yes the >=  was a shameful mistake...